# Throw Causes Program to Crash Instead of going to the Catch Block

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

I am using NetBeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I set set up a

```
try
{
int error;

// Code
if (error) throw error;

}
catch(int errorNumber)
{
// Error handling
}
```

block.  However, when an exception is thrown, I get the following "Signal Caught" box instead of the program going to my catch block.

```
Signal received: SIGABRT (?) with sigcode ? (?)
From process: ?
For program celltowebimage, pid 30,222

You may discard the signal or forward it and you may continue or pause the process
To control which signals are caught or ignored use Debug->Dbx Configure
```

Every other time a program I write throws an exception, it goes to the catch block.  Why is NetBeans crashing the program instead?  An example of the exception number that is thrown is -23.  However they are all small, negative numbers and all result in the same problem.

Comment: I don't think this code is the problem. My guess is some other part of your code is causing the SIGABRT.

Comment: Stop putting the things that should be tags in the subject.  That's why tags exist.

Comment: I commented out everything in the try block and replaced it with "throw -1;".  I still got the SIGABRT window.

Comment: I also tried adding "#include <exception>" to no avail.

Comment: It seems to be related to my calling, within the catch block, my own functions that I have defined outside the actual file that my try/catch blocks are in.  If I include them, I get the SIGABRT.  If I leave them out I do not.